# Stop async process in while loop NODEJS

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, events

How to stop **while** loop in provided code? What code should be in "STOP" condition to stop while loop?

When listener gives another status **while** loop still runs. **const status** values keeps "START". It doesn't change when listener gives new status.

```
constructor(){
    events.on("imdb-scraper-engine", ({status}) =>{
        this.scraper(status);
    });
    this.scraper('INIT');
}

async scraper(status){

while(status == 'START'){
    await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((result)=>{
        console.log(result);
    });

}

    if((status == 'STOP')){console.log('Process was stopped');}
    if((status == 'INIT')){console.log('Engine Initialized')}

}
```

-- ***eidt find out that I always starting new process calling this.scraper in constructor. But still wondering how to stop while loop.***

Comment: first of all why are you using a while loop ?
when the status is 'START' the while loop will be for infinite loop.
Also you are calling the function time and again after every event triggers so the new event has no effect on previous functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it: 


     constructor(){
            events.on("imdb-scraper-engine", ({status}) =>{
                this.scraper(status);
            });
            this.scraper('INIT');
        }

        async scraper(status){
        console.log(status)
        while(status == 'START' && status != 'STOP'){
console.log(status)
            await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((result)=>{
                console.log(result);
            });

        }

            if((status == 'STOP')){console.log('Process was stopped');}
            if((status == 'INIT')){console.log('Engine Initialized')}

        }
```

Comment: can you please check the status under while loop?see edit

Comment: const status values keeps "START". It doesn't change when listener gives new status.

Comment: ok brother, that mean its not issue with while loop, right? how you update your value "STATUS"?

Comment: in the constructos there is event.on who lisens and give new status

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you might be trying to achieved I can layout an idea for you.

> This may not workthough.

```
theLoop; //its a variable

constructor(){
    this.listenEvent();
    this.scraper('INIT');
}
function listenEvent(){
  events.on("imdb-scraper-engine", ({status}) =>{
         if(status=='STOP'){
            clearTimeout(this.theLoop);
         }
         this.scrapper(status);
    });
}
function startWhileLoop() {
   this.theLoop = setTimeout(async function(){ 
       await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((result)=>{
       console.log(result);
     });
   }, 0);
}

scraper(status){
   while(status == 'START'){
     startWhileLoop();
   }
   if((status == 'STOP')){console.log('Process was stopped');}
   if((status == 'INIT')){console.log('Engine Initialized')}
}
```